# Is there a tool to explicitly organize files in Eclipse into groups without moving them into different packages?

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

Is there a plugin that lets you manually add files to lists/categories?  Something like Mylyn but manual and more files--kind of the way Gmail manages mail--a tagging system.

If I let mylyn manage my windows it actually closes them without any way to shut off (Something I absolutely cannot tolerate, I use my open windows to remind me of what I'm working on--my memory absolutely NEEDS the help)--on top of that it automatically adds files to lists just because that list happens to be open when I start doing something else.

I guess I'm thinking of a plugin that offers a different version of the "Package Explorer", one that is organized by task instead of by package hierarchy, and allows you to move files around at will.

...or is there a way to adapt an existing tool to do this (without actually moving the files around, of course!) Bookmarks don't seem to offer a "Grouping" but using a common first word for the description in my bookmarks may work... Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing with it a bit more, it looks like bookmarks might do what I want.  It is possible to filter bookmarks by searching the subject string, so as long as I put tags in the subject string I can select a sub-filter and have it bring up all the relevant files for a given task.

I won't accept this for a while in case someone has a better answer (a plugin perhaps?)